# Is $\sum'_{m,n} 1/(m w_1 +n w_2)^2$ convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I need to calculate $\sum'_{m,n} 1/(m w_1 +n w_2)^2$. The sum runs over all the pairs of integers except one, $m=n=0$. Is it convergent? Is it possible to evaluate this sum numerically (at least approximately) for example for $w_1 =1$ and $w_2 = e^{i \pi/3}$?

Thank you.

Comment: It is convergent because of the exponent (2) in the denominator.   It is possible to evaluate it approximately, taking enough terms in n and m.  You could separate real and imaginary parts of the denominator.  If both $w_1 \ and\ w_2$ are complex, you could run into trouble.

Comment: There are other possible problem cases, basically when $mw_1+nw_2=0$.  You are safe if the real parts of $w_1\ and\ w_2$ have the same sign.

Comment: Note that absolute convergence fails; your series, with some exponent $a$ replacing the 2, converges absolutely iff $a > 2$ (assuming the $w_1, w_2$ satisfy a certain mild condition). See Apostol's book on modular functions for a proof.

Comment: I don't think this converges because this is a sum over two indices not one. See the [Weierstrass elliptic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass%27s_elliptic_functions).

Comment: It diverges because it is a sum over $\mathbb{Z}^n,n = 2$ and the exponent is $\ge -n$. $\int_{x^2+y^2 \ge 1} (x^2+y^2)^{-1}dxdy = \int_1^\infty r^{-2} 2\pi r dr$ The convergent version is the Weierstrass function $\wp_\tau(z) = \frac{1}{z^2}+\sum_{m,n}' \frac1{(z+m+n\tau)^2}-\frac{1}{(m+n\tau)^2}$.

Comment: You are right ! I erase and correct.

Comment: It is an Eisenstein series (see Wikipedia on modular forms) that diverges with exponent 2 ; it converges if you replace it by an exponent 4, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the partial sums
when
$w_1 = w_2 = w$.

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{1 \le m, n \le L} \dfrac1{(nw+mw)^2}
&=\dfrac1{w^2}\sum_{m=1}^L\sum_{n=1}^L\dfrac1{(n+m)^2}\\
&>\dfrac1{w^2}\sum_{m=1}^L\sum_{n=1}^L\dfrac1{(n+m)(n+m+1)}\\
&=\dfrac1{w^2}\sum_{m=1}^L\sum_{n=1}^L(\dfrac1{n+m}-\dfrac1{n+m+1})\\
&=\dfrac1{w^2}\sum_{m=1}^L(\dfrac1{m+1}-\dfrac1{m+L+1})\\
&=\dfrac1{w^2}\sum_{m=2}^{L+1}(\dfrac1{m}-\dfrac1{m+L})\\
&=\dfrac1{w^2}(\sum_{m=2}^{L+1}\dfrac1{m}-\sum_{m=L+2}^{2L+1}\dfrac1{m})\\
&=\dfrac1{w^2}(H_{L+2}-1-(H_{2L+1}-H_{L+1}))
\qquad\text{where } H_k = \sum_{j=1}^k \dfrac1{j}\\
\end{array}
$

Since
$H_k
\approx \ln k +\gamma$,
it is readily shown that
$H_{L+2}-1-(H_{2L+1}-H_{L+1}))
\approx \ln L + c$
for some constant $c$,
so the sum diverges.

Comment: But in my case $w_1 \neq w_2$.